# How to pass a variable in an endpoint call in nodejs

Tags: node.js, rest, api, request, endpoint

I have a variable e.g. `var merchanttoken = requestConfig.merchant_connect_token`, how do I pass it when making an call to an endpoint e.g

`request.get('http://pi.call/v2/{merchanttoken}/info, function)`

I need to pass the variable in the url.

Comment: Just build the URL as a string.  You can either use template literal logic or string addition to add the value onto your base URL.

Comment: Can you show me how ? @jfriend00

Comment: What part do you not understand?  This is very basic string manipulation: `"http://pi.call/v2/" + someStringVariable`.

Comment: Thanks that helped, I was using double quotes this way:

`'/v2/connects/"+merchanttoken+"/info';`

But I saw you used the same quotes tried it and it worked 

`'/v2/connects/'+merchanttoken+'/info';`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend pass it as a POST request instead of GET. Because auth token is sensitive content.

Still if you prefer GET change URL format to this.

`http://pi.call/v2/info?merchanttoken={merchanttoken}`

You can access it at server side nodejs by

```
var url = require('url');
var url_parts = url.parse(request.url, true);
var merchanttoken = url_parts.merchanttoken;
```

Comment: Hi @Harikrishnan, thanks for the help, I am making a server to server call so I don't need to be worried about exposing the token.